# What is the largest value of $n$ for which $2n + 1$ is a factor of $122 + n^{2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, arithmetic, contest-math

Given that $n$ is a natural number, what is its largest value such that  $2n + 1$ is a factor of  $122 + n^{2}$?

Comment: This question has been reposted from Brillant, as a one-step simplification of [this problem](https://brilliant.org/mathematics-problem/greedy-calvinosaurus-dinosaur/?group=oulUEVvkMXdm). Please close this for a week. - Calvin Lin, Brilliant Challenge Master.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $2n+1$ is odd, it divides $n^2+122$ iff it divides $4n^2+488$ and
$$
4n^2+488=(2n+1)(2n-1)+489
$$
Thus, $2n+1\mid489$. The largest such $n$ would be $244$ and if we check
$$
2\cdot244+1\mid244^2+122
$$
Thus, $n=244$ is the largest $n$ so that $2n+1\mid ^2+122$.

Answer (score 6):

Note that $4\cdot(n^2+122) - (2n+1)(2n-1)=489$. Hence if $n^2+122$  is a multiple of $2n+1$, we also need $2n+1\mid 489=2\cdot 244+1$. On the other hand, $n=244$ does indeed lead to $n^2+122 = 122\cdot(2n+1)$, so the largest $n$ is indeed $244$.

Comment: This question has been reposted from Brillant, as a one-step simplification of [this problem](https://brilliant.org/mathematics-problem/greedy-calvinosaurus-dinosaur/?group=oulUEVvkMXdm). Please close this for a week. - Calvin Lin, Brilliant Challenge Master.

Comment: I have _temporarily_ deleted this answer as the question comes from a current Brilliant problem.  The question itself is locked, and will unlock in one week.  At that time your answer will be un-deleted.